# Re-fetch with useSWR hook when React Router Param changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, swr

I've found many questions similar to this, but all of them use normal fetching which could be handled by an useEffect hook, but it's not possible with useSWR.

Heres the code:

```js
// simplified Router component:
export default function Router(){
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<MainPage />} />
          <Route path="post/:id" element={<Post />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
}

// Post.tsx
export default function Post(){
  const {id} = useParams()
  const i = parseInt(id)
  const fetcher = (url) => axios.get(url, {id: i}).then(res => res.data)
  const {data} = useSWR('http://localhost:80/post', fetcher)
  return <div>
           {/*display post content */}
         </div>
}
```

I tried redirecting/reloading with useNavigate() but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could *revalidate* (`mutate`) the call if the *param* changes inside `useEffect`.

```
const { data, mutate } = useSWR('http://localhost:80/post', fetcher);

useEffect(() => {
   mutate('http://localhost:80/post', fetcher);
}, [param]);
```

or use the `param` as a key:

```
const { data, mutate } = useSWR(['http://localhost:80/post', param], fetcher);
```

and slightly modify the `fetcher` function:

```
const fetcher = ([url]) => axios.get(url, {id: i}).then(res => res.data)
```

Comment: It's a get request

Comment: @Adam and what's the difference?

Comment: Retracted my down vote because of your edit. The useEffect approach really isn’t how this should be done.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to update the key that `useSWR` uses (the key is the first argument to `useSWR`) in which case it'll just refetch automatically whenever the id changes, with the correct loading/error/etc states

```
  const {id} = useParams()
  const {data} = useSWR(`http://localhost:80/post/?id=${parseInt(id)}`, (url) => axios.get(url).then(res => res.data))
```

Any dependency (like the id) that is used to make a request should be part of `useSWR`'s key.

EDIT: Which, as the other answer pointed out, can be an array is well, if desired, instead of just a url

Highly recommend [Understanding SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/advanced/understanding#key-change)

Comment: You shouldn't assume that API can handle the `id` param. That's just wrong. If you have chosen the `key`-approach, you should use an array instead where you can specify the `param` as the mutable key. The same as I did in my answer.

Comment: @kinduser, the OP is using axios to make a get request with the id param? how is it an assumption?

Comment: The array as key approach is fine as well